# Field initial data does not display in a ModelSelect2Widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter, django-select2

I am building a *django-filter* `FilterView`, using `ModelSelect2Widget` for some of the filter form fields.

It correctly work to select items, and build the right query params in URL, but when I reload the page, passing the `filter` instance in the context, the `ModelSelect2Widget` **does not display the previously selected item**.

In template I checked that `{{ filter.form.data }}` effectively contains the selected data : it is OK.

In the principle, the codebase is like this :

```py
class BookFilterSet(FilterSet):
   author = MethodFilter(widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
       queryset=User.objects.all(),
       search_fields=['username__icontains',]
   ),
   action = 'no_action'

   def no_action(self, queryset, name, value):
        """a neutral action"""
        return queryset

class FilterView(FilterView):
    filterset_class = BookFilterSet
    template_name = "books.html"
```

Do I need to override some method to display `filter.form.initial` in the `ModelSelect2Widget` ?